# Use read-only xf:input as xf:output in Orbeon?

Tags: orbeon, xforms, xpath-2.0

Can i use a read-only xf:input act like xf:output in Orbeon?
How to set the value of a readonly input field?

*simpler code sample:*

```
<xf:input ref="//Some/Elements/TotalCredit"
          value="round(($quantity) * ($creditPerUnit))">
</xf:input >

<xf:output ref="//Some/Elements/TotalCredit" 
           value="round(($quantity) * ($creditPerUnit))"/>
```

In the above code the *xf:input* shows only the initial value from the model!
It doesn't update!
But *xf:output* value is updated as expected!
[image]

So, how can set *xf:input*'s value like *xf:output*?

- I don't want to use calculation in bind.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you have an `xf:input` with both a `ref` and a `value`; I am not sure what you expect this to do, or if that makes sense, but for sure it currently won't work:

- With the `xf:output`, you can have both a `ref` and a `value`, where the node pointed by `ref` can influence whether the `xf:output` is shown and the `value` gives it its value.
- If you want to do the same with an `xf:input`, it can put the result of your calculation in the `ref` (in your case `round(($quantity) * ($creditPerUnit))`). If that expression returns an atomic value, then the input field will be readonly, which I think should take care of your situation.

Comment: I know the one way of calculation in input's Bind, but in my situation i can't use this way, because the xf:input is inside xf:repeat, and not in it's nodeset! It refers to a node that is outside the repeated nodes.Can i pass to the calculation in Bind a variable from View?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use in the calculation for a field inside the repeat the value of a field outside of the repeat. If this is for a form you created with Form Builder, you can just refer to that value as `$control-name` in the calculation, where `control-name` would be the control name of that field outside of the repeat.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i made it, considering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560527/how-to-do-something-with-selected-values-of-an-xformsselect-every-time-they-cha) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074920/re-initialize-xbl-component-on-xxforms-iteration-moved) posts.

```
    //First Input
    <xf:input ref="//Some/Elements/PreviousInputCreditPerUnit">
      <xf:action ev:event="xforms-enabled xxforms-iteration-moved xforms-value-changed">
        <xf:setvalue 
          ref="//Some/Elements/ReadOnlyInputIK" 
          value="round(($quantity) * ($creditPerUnit))"/>
      </xf:action>
    </xf:input>

    //Second input
    <xf:input ref="//Some/Elements/PreviousInputQuantity">
      <xf:action ev:event="xforms-value-changed">
        <xf:setvalue 
          ref="//Some/Elements/ReadOnlyInputIK" 
          value="round(($quantity) * ($creditPerUnit))"/>
      </xf:action>
    </xf:input>

    //Third ReadOnly Input (acts like xf:output)
    <xf:input ref="//Some/Elements/ReadOnlyInput">
    </xf:input>
```

Note the action event in the first column of my repeated row:

> ev:event="xforms-enabled xxforms-iteration-moved xforms-value-changed"

[See this example from Orbeon.](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/b97726230fbe380c20e7c1dab438f140cf846fde/src/resources-packaged/xbl/orbeon/button/button.xbl#L70)